# I am trying to have the computer generate a number in a list for my game but it always malfunctions

Tags: python

I am making my first python project which is basically a very simple number guessing terminal game and I am currently making the first of 3 levels.

This game works by having python generate a random number in a certain range of numbers, and then the person playing the game has to guess the number and the terminal responds with either, 'Congrats you got the number correct' or 'Oops, you got the number wrong'.

Whenever I run the program, even when I know that I only have 1 number to choose from, the terminal says I got it incorrect even though I know 100% that it is not true. I have tried many different approaches to this. I was thinking of changing the format of the numbers like in a range or something similar and it still does not recognize that I have the number correct.

My code is not the best but I am constantly trying to make it better, so here is the code:

```
import random
import numpy
import time

def get_name():
name = input("Before we start, what is your name?")
print("You said your name was: " + name)

# The Variable 'tries' is the indication of how many tries you have left
tries = 1

while tries < 6:

    def try_again(get_number, random, tries):
        # This is to ask the player to try again
        answer = (input(" Do you want to try again?"))

        if answer != "no":
            print("Alright!, well I am going to guess that you want to play again")
            tries = tries + str(1)
            print("You have used up: " + tries + " Of your tries. Remember, when you use 5 tries the game ends")
            get_number(get_name, random, try_again)

    def find_rand_num(get_number, random, tries):

        num_list = [1,1]
        number = random.choice(num_list)

        # Asks the player for the number
        ques = (input("guess your number, since this is the first level you need to choose a number between 1 and 10  "))
        print(ques)

        if input == number:
            print("Congratulations! You got the number correct!")
            try_again(get_number, random, tries)

        elif input != number:
            tries += 1
            print("Oops, you got the number wrong")
            try_again(get_number, random, tries)
        
    def get_number(get_name, random, try_again, tries, find_rand_num):
    
        # This chooses the number that the player will have to guess                
        print("The computer is choosing a random number between 1 and 10... beep beep boop")
        find_rand_num(get_number, random, tries)


    get_name()
    get_number(get_name, random, try_again, tries, find_rand_num)
```

I recently started learning programming because my dad is also a programmer and I want to be as good as him one day. I also have some other errors after the number generating issue. I would love to hear your ideas on how I can make this part work. Thank you for your time and have a great rest of your day!

Comment: You'll want to compare `ques` and `number`, not `input` and `number`. Also, `ques` will be a string, but `number` will be an integer. You'll want to compare a string with a string or an integer with an integer.

Comment: wow! This took me like 2 days to figure out, thank you! You are such a lifesaver Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the result of input() to *ques*, but then you're not using ques. The mistake is in "if input == number". This isn't checking the result of your previous input call. It's checking if the function itself (input) is equal to an integer number, which it will never will be.

You just meant to check 'number == ques'. However, that won't quite work either. input returns a string value, and you're trying to compare it to an integer. You'll need to cast it to an int, like "if number == int(ques)".

Comment: That also works, thanks Joshua! I was helped earlier by another contributor. I solved this by replacing input with ques, and then I put an str() on the number variable and it works perfectly. Thank you again for contributing